# Role Based Authorization Identity API - registration not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authorization, asp.net-identity

I have been following a Youtube video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IBpZCFbjvA0
to use the identity API to create role-based users for my asp.net core web app. The role creates and stores successfully in my database but I get an error trying to register a user.

The error is:
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request. ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: items Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering.MultiSelectList..ctor(IEnumerable items, string dataValueField, string dataTextField, IEnumerable selectedValues, string dataGroupField).

I have a public github repository along with the full error in the readme.
https://github.com/tripiod8/AUTHORIZATION_EXERCISE3.git

I'm new to learning ASP and I would really appreciate if anybody could explain to me why one of list fields is null.

Thank you very much!

Comment: I could not reproduce your issue by using your github repository.I click the role in the navbar and create the role with name `admin`.Then I click the `register`,the role contains in the dropdownlist.From your error message,it seems you do not create the role successfully.

Comment: The error happens when I register a user with the link beside the login in the nav bar. The role shows in the dropdown when registering, but if I submit then the error happens. It could be possible I'm not saving the role correctly. The error may lay (don't take my word for it) in the 'Data/Migrations/00000000000000_CreateIdentitySchema.cs. Thank you for looking over it!

Comment: Oh,I find the issue.It seems you do not register with the valid name or password,it would return Page(),but you do not set selectlist in your post handler.Just add `ViewData["roles"] = _roleManager.Roles.ToList();` before return page().

Comment: Thank for fixing the problem! It worked and I was able to register successfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The error is: An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request. ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: items Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering.MultiSelectList..ctor(IEnumerable items, string dataValueField, string dataTextField, IEnumerable selectedValues, string dataGroupField).

That is because you do not set the data to selectlist in your post handler.

Add the following code:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string returnUrl = null)
{
    returnUrl = returnUrl ?? Url.Content("~/");
    ExternalLogins = (await _signInManager.GetExternalAuthenticationSchemesAsync()).ToList();
    var role = _roleManager.FindByIdAsync(Input.Name).Result;
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        //...

        foreach (var error in result.Errors)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, error.Description);
        }
    }

    ViewData["roles"] = _roleManager.Roles.ToList();

    return Page();
}
```